# Missing android support library in extras folder, sdk manager

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-sdk-manager

Why I could not find android support library in my extras folder? What should I do? I'm using Eclipse Juno.

Answer (score 3):

The `Android Support Library` entry in the SDK Manager has been deprecated - its last release was version 23.1 of the Support Library (now [8 releases ago](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html)).

You can still find it if you check the **Obsolete** checkbox, but with no modern version, you'll be unable to use any newly introduced APIs or get any bug fixes.

If you wish to use the latest version the Android Support Library, stop using Eclipse (it has been [deprecated for over a year](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html)), switch to Android Studio, and use the `Android Support Repository` from the SDK Manager.

Comment: hmm.. thank you so much but, I can't switch to android studio for now, my project school almost done. btw, do you know how using place picker for eclipse?

Comment: Deprecated means there is no support for using it and you're on your own.